# Springboot - websocket unauthorized 401 with JWT authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

In my project I authenticate logged user by JWT token. I am also creating web socket for chat module, but I cant establish connection with the backend (my front end is fine, I can connect to an example i've found [here](https://github.com/amrkhaledccd/One-to-One-WebSockets-Chat). In the authors code, the chat and auth are separate springboot projects, while I would like to keep it in one place.
I have configured WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
                and().
                authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ws").permitAll().
                // ...
               anyRequest().authenticated().
               and().
exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

My websocket config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/user");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        DefaultContentTypeResolver resolver = new DefaultContentTypeResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        converter.setContentTypeResolver(resolver);
        messageConverters.add(converter);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also I have CORS configured here:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowCredentials(true) //edited, added this.
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see, I think I took care of needed stuff for the cors to work, headers and origins are allowed, added `authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ws").permitAll().` to make sure this endpoint is not validated, and yet something breaks. I'm new to websockets, so I'm sorry if I messed up something elementary, I just cant find fitting solution online.

**EDIT:** I have aded missing `.allowCredentials(true)` in corsConfigurer, now console marks the request not as a failed one, but as an unauthorized (step better I suppose...)

[image: updated]

Comment: after looking at his application i can tell you that you should not follow it. It is teaching bad practices. Implementing any type of custom security is bad practice with the risk of accidentally introducing security issues. He has written a justom JWT token filter which is completely unnecessary since  there is already a built in JWT-filter in spring security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.1/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-sansboot i highly suggest you learn spring security from the official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, authorization was not working due to the fact that i used incorrectly httpSecurity configure().
I've changed

```
 and().
 authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ws").permitAll().
```

to:

```
 and().
 authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll().
```

So all children of this endpoint would be not checked, thus eliminating the 401 response.